# Ubuntu 12.04 LTSP Fat clients autologin and no autologin clients

Tags: 12.04, ltsp

I have 16 clients for my school lab that work perfect with autologin option.
I want to add some other fat clients in teachers room.For them i don't have record for LDM username an password in lts.conf because I want each teacher to use his own credentials. The problem is that after loading the os I have a black screen and no login screen for them.If I add a record in lts.conf they autologin.Is it possible to have a "mix mode"?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks to a greek forum for teachers I found the solution.
You can use:

[Default]
LDM_AUTOLOGIN=True

[teacher_room-mac]
LDM_AUTOLOGIN=False

or the opposite:

[Default]
LDM_AUTOLOGIN=False

[lab-mac]
LDM_AUTOLOGIN=True

The [Default] instructions can be overriden in [mac-address] section.
I chose the first one and works great!